# Untracked files in git

Tags: git, installation

I am new to git. I've just installed git and encountered a problem which is difficult to explain. I'd like to share some screenshots from my git bash, and would appreciate any help from you.
[git commit -m "initial version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsAF8.jpg)
[git status -s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r80I7.jpg)
I am using windows 7 x64...
I don't even know what does "git commit -m "initial version" do, I would be thankful if someone advised me a way to learn git quickly .

I've just installed git following a video lesson on YouTube, but the git version was different from one I downloaded. I was trying to set it up.

````
User@SAMSUNG MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ git commit -m "initial version"```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gcaH.jpg)
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+warning%3A+could+not+open+directory+AppData%2FLocal%2FApplication+Data%2F+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to **edit your files** in the working directory. When you’re ready to save a copy of the current state of the project, **you stage changes** with `git add`. After you’re happy with the staged snapshot, **you commit it to the project history** with `git commit`.

There are very good tutorials around, like [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes) one.

From the git-bash point of view this is:

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial version"
```

The point '.' in `git add` means "all", so all modified files are going to be staged. The `-m` argument in `git commit` is to add an inline message for the commit, "initial version" in this example. Without the `-m` argument, your configured/default text editor is opened so you can add this message.